# не создаётся таблица sql.db

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, сервер

Пишу мессенеджер (сервер-клиент). На сервере хочу создать таблицу с сообщениями, чтобы история сообщений пользователей сохранялась.

```
    public static Connection connection;
    public static Statement database;


    UsersDataBase() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:res/DataBase.db");
            database = connection.createStatement();

            database.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (Login TEXT UNIQUE, Password TEXT)");
            database.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mesage (From TEXT,   To TEXT, Msg TEXT, Date TEXT)");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
```

Это часть класса UsersDataBase.

```
database.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (Login TEXT UNIQUE, Password TEXT)");
```

Таблица users создаётся

```
  database.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mesageFrom TEXT,To TEXT, Msg TEXT, Date TEXT)");
```

А вот таблица mesage нет и я не могу понять почему.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пишите:

```
database.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mesageFrom TEXT,To TEXT, Msg TEXT, Date TEXT)");
```

Похоже отсуствует открывающая скобка и пробелы, попробуйте так:

```
database.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mesage (From TEXT,To TEXT, Msg TEXT, Date TEXT)");
```

Так же `From`, `To` и `Date` могут быть зарезервированными словами СУБД. Попробуйте заключить их в двойные кавычки или заменить